# Halting problem for bounded length programs

Tags: computational-complexity, computability-theory

Consider a set $M_n$ of all Turing machines with at most $n$ states. What is the smallest number of states (asymptotically in $n$) a Turing machine must have in order to solve halting problems for all machines in $M_n$?

Clearly, the answer is at least $n-O(1)$ (use the standard argument showing that the halting problem is undecidable). It is also clear that $\approx n^n$ states suffice since this is roughly the cardinality of the set $M_n$.

Is it possible to prove an exponential lower bound, say?

Comment: Though the exact asymptotics may need to be checked, it seems to me that your question is answered by the section [“Relationship to the halting problem” in Wikipedia's article on Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant#Relationship_to_the_halting_problem).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks! It seems like passing to the prefix-free universal computable function will slightly increase the length, though. Or is it possible to do with the length being $O(n)$ where $n$ is the number of states? If you directly do the sum over possible Turing machines summing something like $n^{-10n}$ for each machine that halts, then knowing $O(n\log{n})$ bits of that number should suffice.